# Colouring Book in 80's about aliens who destroy all nature on their world

Tags: story-identification, books

I had a colouring book in the 80's about an alien species who build a beautiful civilisation... that destroys all nature on their home world. They realize too late what they have lost.

Any clues?

Comment: Hiya. This is an interesting question. One thing that might help is some geographic info. Where were you living at the time? If there were words in the book, which language were they in? Even tiny details can be helpful!

Comment: I was living in South Africa but the book may have been bought in the UK. The visual style stands out so much more than the language but I assume it was in english. The visual style of the aliens was very elegant, elongated and flowing, almost psychedlic.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds somewhat similar to “The Wump World”, a picture book by Bill Peet.

Alien people land on a beautiful grassy world filled with meadows and trees, and tear it all up to build cities, roads, and endless concrete and smog.

The poor cute Wumps flee to survive in caves, until the aliens have consumed all natural resources on the planet and completely covered it in city.

Finally, the polluting aliens all leave in spaceships to find a new world to exploit, and the Wumps emerge and find the last small patch of grass on the planet.

The last picture is of a Wump looking at a new shoot growing up through the concrete and smiling.

[image: Tearing up nature, to build a city]

Comment: That's immediately what I thought of as well, but it's not a coloring book, obviously.

Comment: Looks cool though not the one. The image of a new shoot growing through concrete may have also appeared. The alien civilisation paved over the whole world but also built beautiful buildings.

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a shot. But this one is definitely worth a read if you're ever in a children's library.